# Move selected items multiple rows to another list Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a listbox with multiple (3 columns) selected items and I would like to move only the selected ones to another listbox, but this listbox should also contain 3 columns.
Before selecting new items, I've added the other items to the listbox1 with this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        ListBox1.MultiSelect = 2
        ListBox2.MultiSelect = 2

           Dim RowsNumber As Integer
          Dim RowsNumberOnly As Integer
           Dim i As Integer
          Dim Customers As Long
          Dim customersloop As Long
          Dim test As String
            RowsNumber = FunctionCount.calculateRows
               RowsNumberOnly = FunctionCount.calculateRowsValue

           ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3
            ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50;50;50"

            ListBox2.ColumnCount = 3
            ListBox2.ColumnWidths = "50;50;50"


Customers = 10
i = 0

 For customersloop = Customers To RowsNumber

    ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List(i, 0) = Sheets("Test").Range("J" & customersloop).Value
    ListBox1.List(i, 1) = Sheets("Test").Range("K" & customersloop).Value
    ListBox1.List(i, 2) = Sheets("Test").Range("L" & customersloop).Value
    i = i + 1
  Next



       End Sub
```

After that the selected item need to be transferred to the other listbox2
This is my code:

```
Private Sub SelectItems_btn_Click()
  Dim SelectedItems As String
  Dim i As Integer
   Dim ListBox2i As Integer
 ListBox2i = 0
 For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

  If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then

    Me.ListBox2.Additem
     Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2i, 0) = ListBox1.List(i, 0).Value
     Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2i, 1) = ListBox1.List(i, 1).Value
     Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2i, 2) = ListBox1.List(i, 2).Value
    ListBox2i = ListBox2i + 1
   End If

 Next

End Sub
```

I hope that you could help. I always get the error message that am object is missing.
Best regards

Matthias

Comment: Could you please provide us with the excel-file?

Thank you.

Comment: I have used exactly your code and it is working on my side. Are you sure, that you are targetting correct ListBox?

Comment: Hello Robert I'm always getting the error message Run-time error 424 "Object required". Then i won't work. This appended as the first me.ListBox2.list...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move items from list1 to another list2 you can use the columns property from vba.

this is the solution code after I added the values to my first list1 with 3 columns.

```
Private Sub SelectItems_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
     ListBox2.AddItem
     ListBox2.Column(0, (ListBox2.ListCount - 1)) = ListBox1.Column(0, i)
     ListBox2.Column(1, (ListBox2.ListCount - 1)) = ListBox1.Column(1, i)
     ListBox2.Column(2, (ListBox2.ListCount - 1)) = ListBox1.Column(2, i)

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Best regards